# Why doesn't this object get assigned in this `if` statement in R?

Tags: function, r

I am trying to learn R by working through this [ProjectEuler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1) problem using R.

If I use `cat` in my function I can get the list of correct values:

```
> n <- 1:9
> s <- 0
> ck <- function(n)
+   for(i in n) 
+     if(i/3 == round(i/3) | i/5 == round(i/5)) cat(i) 
> ck(n) 
3569>
```

but if I try to assign these to an object to sum them it doesn't work:

```
> n <- 1:9
> s <- 0
> ck <- function(n)
+   for(i in n) 
+     if(i/3 == round(i/3) | i/5 == round(i/5)) s <- c(s, i) 
> ck(n)
> s
[1] 0
>
```

Why doesn't the second function work?

Thank you.

Comment: Also, for your own sake please use { } in your function, for, and if statements!

Comment: You might also want to consider the `%%` function, which is the *modulo* function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator `n %% 3` for example.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson - thanks for that suggestion, I figured there must have been a better way to do that!

Comment: @Gavin has hinted in this direction, but I'll add the obligatory R vectorization comment: `n[n %% 3 == 0 | n %% 5 == 0]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global / local confusion.  Define `s` *inside* of `ck()`, and return it. Something like

```
   ck <- function(n) {
     s <- 0
     for(i in n) {  
       if(i/3 == round(i/3) | i/5 == round(i/5)) {
         s <- c(s, i) 
       }
     }
     s
   }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't see it, but `n` was a vector in the OP's example... what was the incorrect indexing?

Comment: Oh, right -- corrected. Even then, better to be explicit and use, say, `seq_along()`. But now we're debating style...